# Why is my Google Chat box changing sizes on me as I type?

Tags: gmail, google-talk

I'm using Google Chat on my personal email account with the right-hand-side-chat lab feature enabled.

I noticed tonight that, as I typed, the chatbox would grow to three times as large as normal and vary in size as I typed into it. Below is a screencapture. The box on the left is normal, the box on the right has grown as a result of me tapping Alt to get the screencapture.

[image: chatproblems]

I'm running the latest Chrome, and I tried restarting my browser. I attempted to repro in IE, but I have IE7 which won't display chat.

Update: checking on my office computer, for which my work email uses Google Enterprise Apps, and this problem isn't persisting there. I also logged into my personal email; on my work computer, this chat-box-text-area-resizing issue isn't cropping up.

Update two: The problem followed me to work! I checked in IE9; this issue isn't reproducing there. However, Chrome continues to demonstrate this issue.

Why is my chat window size bouncing around? How can I get it to stabilize?

Comment: I'm having the same problem! Driving me nuts.

Comment: Looks like it’s just a bug, but I don’t have any reference for it. Have you tried clearing your browser’s cache?

Comment: @Alex Tried that, didn't change anything. :/

Comment: @Aarthi I was kinda able to reproduce it by zooming the page in and out, but it’s not permanent, it gets restored once you type a message and send it to the person you are chatting to.

Comment: @Alex wait, you mean this is because I keep my Chrome at 90%? That's freaking ridiculous! Gah!

Comment: Leaving out that you don't default to 100% seems like it might be important

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise I honestly totally forgot I don't keep it at 100%.

Comment: it was driving me crazy too - I also have chrome from 90% to 75% - but I readjusted to 100%, then back down to my preferred size, and the bug went away! So you don't need to *keep* it at 100%... just do a driveby!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that crops up when Gmail is zoomed to anything not 100%. To fix, keep Gmail at 100% in Chrome at all times.